# style a textbox into the following format?

Tags: asp.net

I have a field called WATER METER READING(Right now its a textbox to take 6 numbers) on my HTml page, but I need to change its format to display as  [][][][][][] (6 separate small (single digit forms)).... all 6 fields required and all need to be a number.

finally it should look like this.

Water Meter Reading:* [][][][][][]

Any suggestions how to display the values like this.

Comment: they are not boxes just like this [0][0][0][0][0][0]

Comment: Edit your question if you have additional nformations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it seems to me you want 6 separate fields, WATER_METER_READING_1 through WATER_METER_READING_6 and you can combine them into one field WATER_METER_READING when the form is submitted to the server. Consequently to load the data into the 6 fields if you need to edit the form you can just split the field WATER_METER_READING on the server side into the appropriate field.

Comment: How to seperate the fields and display them exactly as shown above in html.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for regex validation? Try [\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d]

Answer (score 0):

Could you make 6 very narrow textboxes.

Add validation controls to make them required fields.

In code-behind, read the values from the textboxes, and concatenate them into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple span tags and set the background image of those span to the box look you want.
e.g. `<span>0</span><span>9</span><span>5</span><span>7</span><span>8</span>` 
in css set the background image for this spans to your like.

Comment: These are the 6 values where user enter on the front end form.